# Algorithm to find closest tuples for each tuple in a list

Tags: algorithm, avl-tree

Consider an array of elements, where each element is a pair like (a,b)
The first element a is a Date and b is some positive integer.
The given array is sorted based on the Date.
We have to write a function that returns an array of integers.
Each element in the array at ith location is derived from the corresponding tuple element in the original array like following.

Take the ith tuple say (a,b) . Now look at all the tuples which occur after it. And find the one (c,d) such that d is less than b and is maximum.
The ith element in the returnes array will be (c-a).

My thoughts - 
We scan from right side of the given array of tuples. And each time we encounter a tuple we add it in an AVL tree
. Now searching takes time equal to height of tree.
So if the elements are distinct this will work in n log n time.
But if the second element in a tuple occur more times then we may end up traversing the whole tree.
Not sure how to address that.

We could probably store the min and Max nodes in a node for each subtree.

Comment: Were the answer(s) helpful? Let us know if you need any more or different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
//input list of pair is of the form (date, value)
//DS is a data structure that support lower bound search and insert in O(logn)

index = size of list of pair - 1
for (pair p in input list of pair, scanning from right to left):

    //search should return a sentinel if DS is empty
    resultant_array[index--] = pair<p.date, search(previous of lower bound of p.value in DS)?.date>

    if(DS doesn't contain pair with key p.value)
        insert in DS the pair <p.value, p.date>
```

The above algorithm considers highest date if b in (a, b) could be duplicate. To take the lowest date, if p.value exists in DS, update instead of insert on the last line of algorithm.

DS could be ordered map, AVL, red-black, etc. Whole DS doesn't need to be traversed even in case of duplicate values against dates. So, just O(logn) per search.